# Adding a solution file to asp.net 1.1 application using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

I'm trying to migrate an old asp.net 1.1 application to target the new .net 4.0 framework. There are good guides available on this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/september/app-migration-migrate-your-asp-net-1-1-apps-to-visual-studio-2010). However, all approaches start with the assumption that the 1.1 project contains a solution file which one has to open using VS 2010 and go through the conversion wizard.

In my case, the project does not have any solution file, giving me a sort of chicken and egg issue.

Is there a way to add a 1.1 .net soution file with or without VS 2010? Using command line tools? What is so special about a solution file anyway?

Comment: Configuration hell, overload hell, framework hell, versioning hell, dll hell :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the file that you have in a website alreay? Are they located in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\[SITE_FOLDER]?

This site might help as well. http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vshacks_chap1/index.html?page=4

Here is a sample solution:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 7.0
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "C:\...\WebSite1\", "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1", "{A3EF0D1E-ABC0-4A4F-851F-EBC56FDF2C53}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/WebSite1"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\WebSite1\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/WebSite1"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\WebSite1\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "2220"
        DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual Basic"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|.NET = Debug|.NET
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A3EF0D1E-ABC0-4A4F-851F-EBC56FDF2C53}.Debug|.NET.ActiveCfg = Debug|.NET
        {A3EF0D1E-ABC0-4A4F-851F-EBC56FDF2C53}.Debug|.NET.Build.0 = Debug|.NET
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the article. I'll hack around with the files and see where it takes me.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the ASP.NET 1.1 project file. A solution file will be created.

Comment: The application does not have a project file either.

Comment: Sorry, that's not true. You may have _lost_ the project file, but there's no way to have an ASP.NET web application without a project file.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just create a new solution in VS 2010 and then import the 1.1 project into the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the VS 2010/2008/2005 cannot handle .NET 1.1 . VS 2003 which worked with .NET 1.1 cannot be installed on Win 7/Vista workstations. One could use a virtual machine and run XP and VS 2003 on it though but I'm looking for other alternatives.

Comment: @Dhruv: no, they can't handle .NET 1.1, but you don't _want_ them to handle it. You want them to handle your code, which was written for .NET 1.1. Just create a new project, copy the files into the project folder, select "Show all Files" in the Projects menu, then include the files in your project.